# My Xbox 360 powers on but doesn't load up?

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

I have an Xbox 360-S. The green light comes on but that is it. It won't do anything. What do I do? I have tried to restart; taking it apart; but still nothing.

Comment: I assume you're certain your Xbox is properly connected to your TV and that the TV is listening to the correct port, is that correct? Also, from the way you write, I assume that your Xbox 360 S has never worked before (i.e. it is a new console).

Comment: Also, check your [power supply](http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-360/console/check-power-supply). If you aren't getting enough power, it won't function as intended.

Comment: I changed power cords but nothing the green light come but nothing.  The lights in the cinter dose not go around. I was playing it last night

Comment: What do you mean by "taking it apart?" You shouldn't be disassembling complex electronics like an Xbox unless you know exactly what you're doing. You could do more harm than good.

Comment: I would also recommend, if possible, the usage of the AV Cable port above the HDMI port, to see if the console can still transmit to the TV, or whether it needs serious repair

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the HDMI cable, if it has been removed or it just moved and now is not plugged in correctly, then only the green lights turn on, but the system won't load.

Also, if it has been modified (RGH/JTAG), sometimes You have to wait longer for the system to load (up to 5 minutes).

If it has taken some damage (fallen off somewhere, got kicked over, etc.), You should take it for a repair.